# Record with Self-referencing Generic Type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function create<A extends 
   Record<string, (r:{[k in keyof A]: ReturnType<A[k]>}) => any>>   //the Record Value is a function that takes the keys and return values of A as it's argument
   (options:A) : any {
   ...
}
```

so A is a Record with values that are functions that I would like to take the record keys with the return types for those keys as the values. Something like:

```
create({
    test: () => "TEST",
    lower: (r) => r.test.toLowerCase() //r is any here, I want r to have the keys of this record with the values being the Return types of these values
}
```

Is there a way to do this while getting typings for the other values in the same Record?

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense, because in your example the property `a` has type `string`, so this object's type cannot be a subtype of `Record` where the value type is a function.

Comment: @kaya3 - I refined the question a bit.  Please let me know if this makes more sense

Comment: By definition the keys of your `Record<string, ...>` type is every `string`.  So you can't really tell it that `test` is a valid key but `foo` isn't.  This function can be typed, but you need a different approach.  I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you define your `options` as `Record<string, ...>`, that means that every `string` is a valid key of `options`.  So you would not be able to distinguish between valid and invalid keys.

One solution is to use the generic to describe the keys of our mapper.  This is not perfect -- we know that `r.test` exists and is a function, but we don't know the return type and we don't know that it doesn't actually use the argument so we have to pass `r` to call it.

```
type OptionsObject<Keys extends PropertyKey> = {
  [K in Keys]: (r: OptionsObject<Keys>) => any;
}

function create<Keys extends PropertyKey>
   (options: OptionsObject<Keys>) : any {
}

create({
    test: () => "TEST",
    lower: (r) => r.test(r).toLowerCase()
})
```

We can get a bit better by using the generic to describe a `Map` object of the keys and return types.  This is able to recognize that `test` returns `string`, but it can't figure out `lower` and it infers the return type as `unknown`.

```
type OptionsObject<Map> = {
  [K in keyof Map]: (r: OptionsObject<Map>) => Map[K];
}

function create<Map extends {}>
   (options: OptionsObject<Map>) : any {
}

create({
    test: () => "TEST",
    lower: (r) => r.test(r).toLowerCase()
})
```

edit: I think I misunderstood this bit *"the Record Value is a function that takes the keys and return values of A as it's argument"* and what you want is `(r: Map) =>` instead of `(r: OptionsObject<Map>) =>`.

Comment: this is really close (with (r: Map) => ), but as you noted, when you include the argument the type becomes unknown

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I catch idea:

```
type OptionsObject<Map> = {
  [K in keyof Map]: ((K?: any) => Map[K]);
}

function create<Map>(options: any): OptionsObject<Map> {
  return options;
}

const opt = {
  test:  () => "TeSt",
  lower: (r: any) => r.test(r).toLowerCase(),
  upper: (r: any) => r.test(r).toUpperCase()
}

const a = create<typeof opt>(opt)

console.log('a.test()',  a.test())    // "a.test()",  "TeSt" 
console.log('a.lower(a)', a.lower(a)) // "a.lower(a)",  "test" 
console.log('a.upper(a)', a.upper(a)) // "a.upper(a)",  "TEST"
```